# Clojure functions for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure

I wondering if there is a set of Emacs Lisp code that implements some of Clojure's functions.  For example, -> and ->> and comp and partial, and others?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've ported the `->` and `->>` macros to Emacs Lisp a while ago. I use them occasionally in my configuration code and they seem to work fine.

```
(defmacro -> (e &rest es)
  (if (and (consp es) (not (consp (cdr es))))
      (if (consp (car es))
          `(,(caar es) ,e ,@(cdar es))
        `(,(car es) ,e))
    (if (consp es)
        `(-> (-> ,e ,(car es)) ,@(cdr es))
      e)))

(defmacro ->> (e &rest es)
  (if (and (consp es) (not (consp (cdr es))))
      (if (consp (car es))
          `(,@(car es) ,e)
        `(,(car es) ,e))
    (if (consp es)
        `(->> (->> ,e ,(car es)) ,@(cdr es))
      e)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely take a look at [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el). It provides a lot of Clojure-inspired functions like:

- -map `(fn list)`
- -reduce-from `(fn initial-value list)`
- -reduce-r-from `(fn initial-value list)`
- -reduce `(fn list)`
- -reduce-r `(fn list)`
- -filter `(pred list)`
- -remove `(pred list)`
- -keep `(fn list)`
- -map-when `(pred rep list)`
- -map-indexed `(fn list)`
- -flatten `(l)`
- -concat `(&rest lists)`
- -mapcat `(fn list)`
- -cons* `(&rest args)`
- -count `(pred list)`
- -any? `(pred list)`
- -all? `(pred list)`
- -none? `(pred list)`
- -only-some? `(pred list)`
- -each `(list fn)`
- -each-while `(list pred fn)`
- -dotimes `(num fn)`
- -repeat `(n x)`
- -slice `(list from &optional to)`
- -take `(n list)`
- -drop `(n list)`
- -take-while `(pred list)`
- -drop-while `(pred list)`
- -split-at `(n list)`
- -insert-at `(n x list)`
- -split-with `(pred list)`
- -separate `(pred list)`
- -partition `(n list)`
- -partition-all-in-steps `(n step list)`
- -partition-in-steps `(n step list)`
- -partition-all `(n list)`
- -partition-by `(fn list)`
- -partition-by-header `(fn list)`
- -group-by `(fn list)`
- -interpose `(sep list)`
- -interleave `(&rest lists)`
- -zip-with `(fn list1 list2)`
- -zip `(list1 list2)`
- -first `(pred list)`
- -last `(pred list)`
- -union `(list list2)`
- -difference `(list list2)`
- -intersection `(list list2)`
- -distinct `(list)`
- -contains? `(list element)`
- -sort `(predicate list)`
- -partial `(fn &rest args)`
- -rpartial `(fn &rest args)`
- -applify `(fn)`
- -> `(x &optional form &rest more)`
- ->> `(x form &rest more)`
- --> `(x form &rest more)`
- -when-let `(var-val &rest body)`
- -when-let* `(vars-vals &rest body)`
- -if-let `(var-val then &optional else)`
- -if-let* `(vars-vals then &optional else)`
- !cons `(car cdr)`
- !cdr `(list)`

I find this library extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the others, but partial is implemented in the lexbind branch of Emacs as "curry".

Answer (score 0):

I've written these macros recently.
They're not recursive and are less verbose.
But I haven't tested them extensively yet.

```
(defmacro ->> (x &rest forms)
  (while forms
      (setq x (append (pop forms) (list x))))
    x)

(defmacro -> (x &rest forms)
  (while forms
    (let ((form (pop forms)))
      (push x (cdr form))
      (setq x form)))
  x)
```